# What is the better option to include some "snapshots" of HTML pages in Beamer?

Tags: graphics

I am giving a presentation (in beamer) about creating HTML pages. I want to include some sort of "snapshot" of the created HTML file within the presentation. I am looking for something like `pdfpages` except for a webpage. Here are some of the things I tried and was not really happy with:

- Take a screenshot: shows lots of extra stuff (browser menus, etc), and difficult to show the entire file which is longer than one page
- Convert the webpage to pdf: I do have Acrobat Professional, and can convert a webpage to a pdf file and then use `pdfpages`, but it adds extra headings (small problem), and cannot convert a file with frames
- Include just a link to the file, which will open in a browser: workable for the presentation, but makes distribution of the talk more difficult as extra files are needed

Are there better options? Can my solutions be improved?

Comment: How many html pages do you have?

Comment: The files are not long, 2-3 pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Take the screenshots using the trial version of [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/). SnagIt allows you to take a sreenshot of a scrollable html page as a single image.

  [image]
- Slice the large image using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=uu3u3gtj58joge1et6f7j8ffn4#windows) and save the smaller images in PNG format. Read [how to slice an image using ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile).
- Import the PNG images from Beamer and make sure you compile the input file using pdflatex.

**Disclaimer:** I am NOT affiliated with [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/) and  ImageMagick in any way. This is an example of a scrollable HTML page taken by SnagIt:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option is to use some sort of clever screen shot tool to take screenshots of part of a window. For example, [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is a linux app that allows you to drag out a rectangle of part of your screen and save that as a png. These can then be included in beamer directly, as long as you're compiling with pdflatex. I'm sure a similar tool for windows/Macs exists...

If you had lots of these html things you wanted including, you could write a script to load each one, do "print to file" to create a pdf and then include it with judicious use of `pdfcrop` to take out headers you don't want etc...

Comment: By the way, the default gnome screenshot can do rectangular areas of the window.

Comment: @Andrew and @Seamus: Can it take a scrollable html page as a single image?

Comment: @xport: No. But one option is to zoom the browser window to the point at which the whole document fits on one screen.

Comment: @xport: Or, given that a whole HTML page shown in one picture is going to be beyond the audiences' ability to see any detail, using the rectangular screen capture, simply select the exact area wanted for each image.  No need to split up the image afterwards.

Comment: @Andrew: I see. But it will be difficult to get a consistent splitting frame for a bunch of scrollable html pages. Two or more split images can have overlapped or redundant strips.

Comment: @xport I don't think this is a serious problem. Since these are going to be included in a TeX file, they will need to be cut up anyway...

Comment: Thanks! This is clearly workable, but needs a lot of fiddling.

Comment: @Seamus: Yes. I agree with you. It is just an option for a perfectionist. :)

Answer (score 3):

I usually stick to opensource tools, so I'd like to suggest the use of [zscreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/), if you are using Windows. Worth a shot.

If you use Linux, I second Seamus on [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), it's a great tool.

Comment: Can zscreen take a scrollable html page as a single image?

Comment: @xport: If I'm not wrong, there is an option, __Capture > Webpage__. I don't believe it can handle pages that require login, since there's no user input.

Comment: It cannot take a scrollable html page.

Comment: @xport: I installed zscreen in my Windows machine, went to [this tab](http://i.imgur.com/jGWHW.png) and got [this result](http://i.imgur.com/ZiyFj.jpg). Only if I'm confused with the meaning of _scrollable HTML page_. =)

Comment: "Scrollable HTML page" is my own terminology. It stands for a HTML page that can be scrolled on the browser in maximized mode. Btw, you need to specify the exact width and height to remove the scroll bar when using zscreen.

Comment: [ZScreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/) seems to have been replaced by [ShareX](http://code.google.com/p/sharex). However, as mentioned in the [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/sharex/wiki/WebPageCapture), Google Chrome has a [Screen Capture extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) which works like a charm...